# JBOSS 6.2 EAP Missing Dependents Data-Source

Tags: jboss, oracle11g, jboss5.x, jboss6.x

Adding an update:
I was able to resolve. Grabbed ojdbc6.jar and used instead of 14. I resolved by changing the name in `<driver>oracle</driver>` to the name of the .jar `<driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>` which allowed the data source to use the oracle driver of ojdbc6.

From what I have learned we don't have to create a module, but can place the .jar into the deploy file and JBOSS will deploy on the fly. We just need to reference in the driver name. For me the module wasn't adding correctly so it was nice to find this alternative solution. Not sure to the downside at this time.

```
####### Original Problem Below #######
```

Looking for some help with a data-source error. I am migrating a 5.1 JBOSS application to a 6.2 JBOSS application. After spending a couple days online learning how to configure JBOSS 6.2 I am getting the below error. Migration to JBOSS 6.2 is required by our team. I have tried several different ways to configure the XML. I have tried the module vs placing the .jar in deploy folder.

My current set up is as follows:

ojdbc14.jar is in deploy folder

I have updated the standalone.xml as below:

```
 <datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/CCASDataSource"
    pool-name="CCASDataSource"
    enabled="true"
    use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@##########:1521:########</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <pool>
    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
    <user-name>######</user-name>
    <password>###### </password>    
    </security>
    </datasource>   
    </datasources>
```

Error:

> 15:00:41,684 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version
>   1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
>
> 15:00:42,089 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version
>   1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
>
> 15:00:42,151 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899:
>   JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) starting
>
> 15:00:43,381 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found ccas.ear in
>   deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called
>   ccas.ear.dodeploy
>
> 15:00:43,403 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO Version
>   3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
>
> 15:00:43,404 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding
>   (management-http)
>
> 15:00:43,410 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO
>   Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
>
> 15:00:43,417 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss
>   Remoting version 3.2.18.GA-redhat-1
>
> 15:00:43,470 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 42) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
>
> 15:00:43,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   37) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
>
> 15:00:43,490 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
>
> 15:00:43,500 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5)
>   JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1
>
> 15:00:43,504 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   35) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main,
>   1.2]
>
> 15:00:43,520 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
>
> 15:00:43,523 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1)
>   JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
>
> 15:00:43,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service
>   thread 1-6) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar
>   1.0.23.Final-redhat-1)
>
> 15:00:43,582 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread
>   1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
>
> 15:00:44,281 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service
>   thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server
>   4.2.3.Final-redhat-1
>
> 15:00:44,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC
>   service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService
>   for directory C:\jboss-eap-6.2_CCAS\standalone\deployments
>
> 15:00:44,307 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ccas.ear"
>   (runtime-name: "ccas.ear")
>
> 15:00:44,308 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ojdbc14.jar"
>   (runtime-name: "ojdbc14.jar")
>
> 15:00:44,367 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name:
>   "ccas.war")
>
> 15:00:44,412 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7)
>   JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
>
> 15:00:44,416 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8)
>   JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
>
> 15:00:44,454 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-6)
>   JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on :
>   http-dev.mytest.com/127.0.0.1:8080
>
> 15:00:44,491 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-6)
>   JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on:
>   http-dev.mytest.com/127.0.0.1:8080
>
> 15:00:44,942 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000128: Infinispan version:
>   Infinispan 'Delirium' 5.2.7.Final
>
> 15:00:44,986 INFO 
>   [org.infinispan.factories.TransactionManagerFactory] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000161: Using a batchMode transaction manager
>
> 15:00:44,987 INFO 
>   [org.infinispan.factories.TransactionManagerFactory] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000161: Using a batchMode transaction manager
>
> 15:00:45,168 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully
>   registered to the platform MBean server.
>
> 15:00:45,169 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully
>   registered to the platform MBean server.
>
> 15:00:45,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 65) JBAS010281: Started local-web cache from web
>   container
>
> 15:00:45,172 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 67) JBAS010281: Started default-host/ccas cache from
>   web container
>
> 15:00:45,182 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67)
>   JBAS018210: Register web context: /ccas
>
> 15:00:45,748 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   26) JBAS018559: Deployed "ojdbc14.jar" (runtime-name : "ojdbc14.jar")
>
> 15:00:45,748 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   26) JBAS018559: Deployed "ccas.ear" (runtime-name : "ccas.ear")
>
> 15:00:45,749 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   JBAS014774: Service status report
>
> JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>
> ```
>   service jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:/jdbc/CCASDataSource, service
> ```
>
> jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/CCASDataSource]
>
> 15:00:45,811 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961:
>   Http management interface listening on
>   http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
>
> 15:00:45,811 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951:
>   Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
>
> 15:00:45,812 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875:
>   JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started (with errors) in
>   4518ms - Started 360 of 430 services (3 services failed or missing
>   dependencies, 66 services are passive or on-demand)

Comment: FYI, ojdbc14.jar is ancient.  You should not be using it.

Comment: I have been trying both ojdbc6 & 14 to no avail.

Comment: If you post your answer I can reward you the points @OldProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the oracle jdbc driver e.g. ojdcb6.jar as a JBoss *module* into the JBoss node before you deploy your app. This also allows you to test your datasource connection is working through the JBoss console (and/or CLI) before you deploy your app.

Create the following directory path:

```
${JBOSS_HOME}\modules\com\oracle\ojdbc6\main
```

Place your ojdbc6.jar in here, and also create a `module.xml` file in the same directory with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle" slot="main">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Then in your JBoss `standalone.xml` file - in your  section add

```
<drivers>
    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
         <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

The definitive solution is in the Redhat site - see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/93693 ... You will need a redhat support account to access this.

Comment: Your naming is off slightly but the concept looks like how every post I see is doing this module, but we don't have to create a module though. This is what I did above.